# Pasar query de sql a EntityFramework c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Tengo el siguiente query realizado en un procedimiento almacenado

```
    SELECT adm_cedula AS CEDULA,adm_apellido+' '+adm_nombre as NOMBRE, adm_cargo AS CARGO , adm_seccion AS SECCION,  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),CAST(DATEADD(D,0,adm_fec_afi) AS DATE),105) AS FECHAA,
CAST(DATEADD(D,0,adm_fec_sal) AS DATE) AS FECHASAL ,adm_cta_cte AS CTA, adm_sueldo as SUELDO , adm_sueldo_otros AS OTROS, adm_dias_gan as DIASG FROM TBL_ADMIN
 WHERE adm_apellido+' '+adm_nombre = @OBRERO and adm_fec_afi >= '1899-12-30';
```

Adjunto la descripción de mi tabla para entender un poco el porque la aplicación del convert y el cast

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al tratar de pasarlo a `EntityFramework` como podría usar el `CONVERT` y el `CAST` hay manera de proceder o lo dejo como sp.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda y guía.

Comment: Has probado con `EntityConnection`  pasandole un comando ? aquí te dejo un link interesante donde hacen lo que comentas https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/Querying-with-EDM.aspx

Comment: Debes agregar el codigo que has intentado para poder corregir sobre eso, se toma a mal que dejen la pregunta sin nada sobre lo que corregir.

Comment: @RamiroBarone lamentablemente no tengo idea de como proceder con esas conversiones que son de sql

Comment: Pon tus tablas para tener más idea de lo que quieres hacer

Comment: @Japv acabo de a;adir la estructura.

Comment: Y qué es lo que haces con tus campos fechas, le sumas x cantidad de días, dame todos los detalles para poderte ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime fecha = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30);
string obrero = "Timoteo";
var lista = from t in tbl_admin
            let NombreCompleto = t.adm_apellido + " " + t.adm_nombre
            where NombreCompleto == obrero && t.adm_fec_afi >= fecha
            select new
            {
                Cedula = t.adm_cedula,
                Nombre = NombreCompleto,
                Cargo = t.adm_cargo,
                Seccion = t.adm_seccion,
                FechaA = t.adm_fec_afi.ToString(),
                FechaSal = t.adm_fec_sal.ToString(),
                CTA = t.adm_cta_cte,
                Sueldo = t.adm_sueldo,
                Otros = t.adm_sueldo_otros,
                DiasG = t.adm_dias_gan
            };
```

Haces tu **consulta** **Linq**, usas la **cláusula let** para concatenar el apellido y el nombre almacenando está concatenación en la **variable temporal NombreCompleto**, la cual será usada más adelante, de esta forma reduces la complejidad del código, usas la **cláusula where** para hacer los filtros correspondientes y posteriormente utilizando la **cláusula select** construyes un **objeto anónimo** con las propiedades correspondientes. Si las fechas deseas guardarlas como **string** haces lo siguiente:

```
FechaA = t.adm_fec_afi.ToString();
```

Si deseas dejar las fechas con el tipo **DateTime** pones solo esto:

```
FechaA = t.adm_fec_afi;
```

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 1):

Basándome en tus indicaciones y ayuda así quedaría finalmente el código para el cual necesitaba esa conversión, posterior valida si devolvió algún valor distinto de null y asigno a las variables correspondientes haciendo uso de foreach.

```
try
            {
                DateTime fecha = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30);
                using (Entities_Sisrol db = new Entities_Sisrol())
                {
                    var lista = from t in db.TBL_ADMIN
                                let NombreCompleto = t.adm_apellido + " " + t.adm_nombre
                                where NombreCompleto == sValue && t.adm_fec_afi >= fecha
                                select new
                                {
                                    Cedula = t.adm_cedula,
                                    Nombre = NombreCompleto,
                                    Cargo = t.adm_cargo,
                                    Seccion = t.adm_seccion,
                                    FechaA = t.adm_fec_afi.ToString(),
                                    FechaSal = t.adm_fec_sal.ToString(),
                                    CTA = t.adm_cta_cte,
                                    Sueldo = t.adm_sueldo,
                                    Otros = t.adm_sueldo_otros,
                                    DiasG = t.adm_dias_gan
                                };
                    if (lista != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in lista)
                        {
                            txtCedula.Text = item.Cedula;
                            txtCodigo.Text = "-";
                            txtCargo.Text = item.Cargo;
                            txtSeccion.Text = item.Seccion;
                            txtCtaCte.Text = item.CTA;
                            txtFecAfi.Text = item.FechaA;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "SISROL", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```